# Measure Node.js total inbound/outbound traffic generated through net.server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got that nifty App I work on, now to calculate some scenarios I'd like to know
how much inbound / outbound traffic is generated per session by the app itself.
I don't want to use the browser for this but to gather that info from the server side.

nodejs net.server does not have any methods that fit the description,
I found only net.socket methods:

`socket.bytesRead` The amount of received bytes.

`socket.bytesWritten` The amount of bytes sent.

do they apply to the traffic generated through net.server?
any existing node_modules that gather that kind of stats?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's because [`net.server`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server) uses [`net.socket`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket). To get the totals, you will have to add `bytesRead` and `bytesWritten` to the totals once the socket is closed. Example:

```
const net = require("net");

var server = net.createServer(function (c) {
    c.on('close', function () {
        // add to the totals
        server.bytesSent += c.bytesWritten;
        server.bytesReceived += c.bytesRead;
    });

    c.write('Hello world!\r\n');
    c.pipe(c);
    c.end();
});

server.bytesReceived = 0;
server.bytesSent = 0;

server.listen(3000);

var time = process.hrtime();
setInterval(function (){
    process.stdout.write('\u001B[2J\u001B[0;0f');
    var diff = process.hrtime(time)[0] + process.hrtime(time)[1]/1000000000;
    var bpsSent = Math.round(server.bytesSent/diff) || 0;
    var bpsReceived = Math.round(server.bytesReceived/diff) || 0;
    console.log("Running node.js %s on %s-%s", process.version, process.platform, process.arch);
    console.log("Memory usage: %d bytes", process.memoryUsage().rss);
    console.log("Uptime: %ds", Math.round(process.uptime()));
    console.log("Open connections: %d", server.connections);
    console.log("In: %d bytes (%d bytes/s)", server.bytesReceived, bpsReceived);
    console.log("Out: %d bytes (%d bytes/s)", server.bytesSent, bpsSent);
}, 100);
```

If you need to update the totals in real-time (when data is received/sent), you can instead add the length of the buffers directly to the totals when they are written/read. This is especially good when you have sockets that are open for a long time and transferring large amounts of data.

```
var server = net.createServer(function (c) {
    var oldWrite = c.write;
    c.write = function(d) {
        if (!Buffer.isBuffer(d)) {
            d = new Buffer(d);
        }
        oldWrite.call(this, d);
        server.bytesSent += d.length;
    };

    c.on('data', function(d){
        server.bytesReceived += d.length;
    });

    c.write('Hello world!\r\n');
    c.pipe(c);
    c.end();
});
```

Comment: I suspected that this runs over the net.socket but the docs aren't specific about it or I'm blind :) thank you for the pro answer!

Comment: @PJJ Yeah, the docs are a bit lacking. Added a second method to update the totals in real-time. Happy I could help! :)